# Android proguard minifyEnabled true + multidex = error

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard, android-multidex

When I start my app I have a lot of warnings and errors:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>   Warning:butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$IdScanner: can't
>   find superclass or interface com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner
>   Warning:butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$RClassScanner: can't
>   find superclass or interface com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner
>   Warning:butterknife.compiler.ButterKnifeProcessor$VarScanner: can't
>   find superclass or interface com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner
>   Warning:org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.DummyGraphics2d: can't find
>   superclass or interface java.awt.Graphics2D
>   Warning:org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.EscherGraphics: can't find
>   superclass or interface java.awt.Graphics
>   Warning:org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.EscherGraphics2d: can't find
>   superclass or interface java.awt.Graphics2D
>   Warning:org.apache.poi.poifs.crypt.dsig.SignatureMarshalListener:
>   can't find superclass or interface org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener
>   Warning:org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFRenderingHint: can't find
>   superclass or interface java.awt.RenderingHints$Key
>   ....
>   Error:Execution failed for task >':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
>   Job failed, see logs for details

My progard-rules is:

> ```
> # Workaround for ProGuard not recognizing dontobfuscate
> -dontobfuscate
> -dontoptimize
> -optimizations !code/allocation/variable
> #Rules for javascript and webview
> -keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
>    public *;
> }
> -keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
> #Parcel
> -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
> }
> -keep class org.parceler.Parceler$$Parcels
> -keep public class org.apache.poi.** {*;}
> #BUTTERKNIFE
> # Retain generated class which implement ViewBinder.
> -keep public class * implements butterknife.internal.ViewBinder
> ```
>
> { public(); }
>
> ```
> # Prevent obfuscation of types which use ButterKnife annotations since the simple name
> # is used to reflectively look up the generated ViewBinder.
> -keep class butterknife.*
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <methods>; }
> -keepclasseswithmembernames class * { @butterknife.* <fields>; }
> ```

My gradle:

```
buildTypes { release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        } }
```

if i change  minifyEnabled false. There are no errors. I am using multidex mode. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
add this line in build.gradle app level dependencies

**compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'**

**dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }**

**minifyEnabled false**

**multiDexEnabled true**

Comment: Ashish, I have all this dependencies. I wrote above if I have  minifyEnabled false everething all right, but I need to obfuscated code.